# Order of eigenvectors in dsygv

Tags: fortran, fortran90, lapack

When I call `dsygv`, I obtain the eigenvectors as a matrix. Are these eigenvectors along the columns or along the rows of the matrix ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Along the columns

Comment: Yes, pretty sure, why? Are you getting inconsistent results?

Comment: No, I also expected to be along the columns, but the code I have stored it by row, and then uses TRANSPA option in many LAPACK calls. The fact is that I wasn't able to find where the transpose was done, so I double asked before investing time in a hunt for something that may have not been there at all. Then I found it. Thanks